# After encoding UTF-16, the string is broken if I want to use in iTextSharp

Tags: sqlite, pdf, encoding, itext, utf-16

Firstly I am getting some informations from a text file, later these informations are added to pdf files' meta data. In the "Producer" section an error was occured about Turkish characters as `ğ`, `ş`. And I solved the problem via using `UTF-16` like this:

```
write.Info.Put(new PdfName("Producer"), new PdfString("Ankara Üniversitesi Hukuk Fakültesi Dergisi (AÜHFD), C.59, S.2, y.2010, s.309-334.", "UTF-16"));
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]
Then, I am getting all pdf files with `foreach` loop and reading meta data and insert into SQLite database file. The problem occurs right here. Because when I want to get from pdf file and set to database file `UTF-16` encoded string (Producer data), it arises strange characters like this:

[image]

[image]

I don't understand, why it occurs error.

EDIT: Here is my all codes. The following codes get meta data from text file and insert pdf files' meta meta section:

```
    var articles = Directory.GetFiles(FILE_PATH, "*.pdf");
    foreach (var article in articles)
    {
        var file_name = Path.GetFileName(article);
        var read = new PdfReader(article);
        var size = read.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
        var doc = new Document(size);
        var write = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(TEMP_PATH + file_name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
        // Article file names like, 1.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf....
        // article_meta_data.txt file content like this: 
        //1@Article 1 Tag Number@Article 1 first - last page number@Article 1 Title@Article 1 Author@Article 1 Subject@Article 1 Keywords
        //2@Article 2 Tag Number@Article 2 first - last page number@Article 2 Title@Article 2 Author@Article 2 Subject@Article 2 Keywords
        //3@Article 3 Tag Number@Article 3 first - last page number@Article 3 Title@Article 3 Author@Article 3 Subject@Article 3 Keywords
        var pdf_file_name = Convert.ToInt32(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(article)) - 1;
        var line = File.ReadAllLines(FILE_PATH + @"article_meta_data.txt");
         var info = line[pdf_file_name].Split('@');

            var producer = Kunye(info); // It returns like: Ankara Üniversitesi Hukuk Fakültesi Dergisi (AÜHFD), C.59, S.2, y.2010, s.309-334.
            var keywords = string.IsNullOrEmpty(info[6]) ? "" : info[6];
            doc.AddTitle(info[3]);
            doc.AddSubject(info[5]);
            doc.AddCreator("UzPDF");
            doc.AddAuthor(info[4]);
            write.Info.Put(new PdfName("Producer"), new PdfString(producer, "UTF-16"));
            doc.AddKeywords(keywords);
            doc.Open();
            var cb = write.DirectContent;
            for (var page_number = 1; page_number <= read.NumberOfPages; page_number++)
            {
                doc.NewPage();
                var page = write.GetImportedPage(read, page_number);
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
            doc.Close();
            read.Close();
            File.Delete(article);
            File.Move(TEMP_PATH + file_name, FILE_PATH + file_name);
    }
```

And the following codes get data from files and insert SQLite database file. For database operation, I am using [Devart - dotConnect for SQLite](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/).

```
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(FILE_PATH, "*.pdf");
    var connection = new Linq2SQLiteDataContext();
    TruncateTable(connection);
    var i = 1;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var read = new PdfReader(file);
        var title = read.Info["Title"].Trim();
        var author = read.Info["Author"].Trim();
        var producer = read.Info["Producer"].Trim();
        var file_name = Path.GetFileName(file)?.Trim();
        var subject = read.Info["Subject"].Trim();
        var keywords = read.Info["Keywords"].Trim();
        var art = new article
        {
            id = i,
            title = (title.Length > 255) ? title.Substring(0, 255) : title,
            author = (author.Length > 100) ? author.Substring(0, 100) : author,
            producer = (producer.Length > 255) ? producer.Substring(0, 255) : producer,
            filename = file_name != null && (file_name.Length > 50) ? file_name.Substring(0, 50) : file_name,
            subject = (subject.Length > 50) ? subject.Substring(0, 50) : subject,
            keywords = (keywords.Length > 500) ? keywords.Substring(0, 500) : keywords,
            createdate = File.GetCreationTime(file),
            update = File.GetLastWriteTime(file)
        };
        connection.articles.InsertOnSubmit(art);
        i++;
    }
    connection.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: "*I am getting all pdf files with foreach loop and reading meta data and insert into SQLite database file. **The problem occurs right here.** Because when I want to get from pdf file and set to database file UTF-16 encoded string (Producer data), it arises strange characters like this*" - If the *problem occurs right there*, you probably should provide thee code doing exactly that if you want to get help concerning that problem.

Comment: @mkl Yes, exactly! When you look pdf files' meta data, everything is fine. But when you want to get and insert to database, the other fields - like title, subject, keywords - do not indicate any problem. But "Producer" field occurs problem. I think I set it with `UTF-16`. So it occured from this reason. But if I do not set with `UTF-16`, unicode charcters fall down.

Comment: Please do show your code doing exactly *that* (i.e *getting all pdf files with foreach loop and reading meta data and insert into SQLite database file*), so people here have a chance to help you.

Comment: It should be pretty easy to write a 20 to 30 line program that shows the problem, both creating a PDF and reading from it, can you provide that? Start from scratch just for the sake of this discussion because that's what we're going to be doing in order to help you. Only use the minimum amount of complexity that still has the problem.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Exactly. Sorry for my impetuosity. I will edit my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: @HabipOĞUZ You added your code of *setting the metadata*. As written above, your code of *reading meta data and inserting into SQLite* is of interest, though.

Comment: Also, to further help us, can you remove as many dependencies and complexities as you can? For instance, you are looping over a bunch of files, can it just be a single file and still have the issue? If so, for this discussion's sake, get rid of the loop. Also, you are setting meta attributes _and_ importing pages, do you need the latter for this discussion? This is why I suggested creating something from scratch that we can copy and paste in VS with minimal changes and debug.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, because I have a lot of articles formatted as ´.pdf´. For writing meta data to pdf file, I get an instance of pdf file (recreate it). Because I don't know directly inserting meta data to pdf file. So I have to get an instance of file. I realize that was a bit confused. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
new PdfString(producer, "UTF-16")
```

Use:

```
new PdfString(producer, PdfString.TEXT_UNICODE)
```

UTF-16 is a specific way to store Unicode values but you don't need to worry about that, iText will take care of everything for you.

Comment: Correct. "UTF-16" actually seems to default to UTF-16LE (little-endian) but PDF requires UTF-16BE (big-endian).

Comment: I should say to you in all my sincerity, today you made me a great favor. Thank you so much.